# Default date format in Apps Script (formatDate)

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I define the format in which I want the timestamp?

For instance, it currently uses

```
var timestamp = new Date();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var timezone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var timeString = Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, timezone, 'HH:mm');
  var dayString = Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, timezone, 'EEE');
  var start = appendRowsToArchiveSheetSettings.timeLimits.startTime;
  var end = appendRowsToArchiveSheetSettings.timeLimits.endTime;
  var days = appendRowsToArchiveSheetSettings.timeLimits.days;
  if ((start && timeString < start) || (end && timeString > end) || (days.length && days.indexOf(dayString) === -1)) {
    return;
  }
```

It gives the timestamp in the following format - **m/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss**

I want the format as **dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss**

What can I do here?

I tried the following snippet to get the current date from the active sheet and show it in the specified format.

```
const DATE = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const FormattedDATE = Utilities.formatDate(DATE, "GMT", "EEEEE, dd MMMM yyyy");
```

Getting the following error -
Exception: The parameters (SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet,String,String) don't match the method signature for Utilities.formatDate.

Comment: Use `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 1):

Creating a timestamp:

```
function myfunk() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone() "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  return ts;
}
```

Note this return a string not a date.

- [Date Format Ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I'm getting the following error:

Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line

What am I missing?

Comment: Add a comma next to `ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone()` so that it'll look like `Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");` and the custom function should work @rohanrg.

Comment: Such a simple miss @Saddles! Updated it and tried but its still showing the format as m/dd/yyyy

Comment: I tried what was answered, and it's working fine for me. You should create a new spreadsheet to test if it works there, and if it does, it's likely that your other file has another function being executed, not the one above.